# Would Brexit have gone ahead by now if Gina Miller had not forced the Government to involve Parliament?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit

Background ([from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gina_Miller)):

> In June 2016, in the aftermath of the United Kingdom European Union membership referendum, [Gina] Miller privately engaged the City of London law firm Mishcon de Reya to challenge the authority of the British Government to invoke Article 50 of the Treaty on European Union using prerogative powers, arguing that only Parliament can take away rights that Parliament has granted.
>
> On 3 November 2016, the High Court of Justice ruled that Parliament had to legislate before the Government could invoke Article 50.

If Miller hadn't done this, would May's deal (or something else) have rolled through, and the whole sorry mess be over by now?

Comment: @chirlu Thanks. Rightfully admonished for sheer sloppiness on my part!

Comment: the assumption behind the question isn't quite right: if May's deal rolls through, the Brexit process will go on for another 10-20 years, as hundreds of international deals have to be renegotiated. Brexit is a long long process, not an event. It will be a long long time before the whole sorry mess is over.

Comment: Moo's answer is incorrect, please remove the tick so as not to mislead readers.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Gina Miller's case has not changed the current situation at all, as the changes required to British law to enact Brexit *require* acts of Parliament, and always did. Gina Miller's case was solely about whether the government could enact Article 50 without an act of Parliament though executive powers, not about the subsequent process.

Comment: If they had invoked Article 50 without needing to consult parliament they would not have offered a meaningful vote, so Miller was instrumental in preventing brexit.

Comment: @user that's nothing more than baseless speculation.

Comment: This is true.

But it seems to me that if anything the Miller case /accelerated/ the process.  Article 50 itself is clear that it has to be invoked by the member state's constitutional processes.  The ruling in the Miller case was that in the UK that meant legislation.  If the government had purported to invoke Article 50 without legislation - and then subsequently lost a legal challenge to that decision - they could have ended up seeing it nullified by the European Court, which would have at least delayed the whole process.

Comment: @Hedgehog It's doubtful that any European court would have nullified the act, as they tend not to get involved in member states governance processes - of which this is most certainly one.

Comment: @Moo The government made that argument in court and was intending to proceed on that basis. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union_(Notification_of_Withdrawal)_Act_2017

Comment: @user what part of that Wikipedia page supports your argument?

Comment: Apologies, wrong link. Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(Miller)_v_Secretary_of_State_for_Exiting_the_European_Union . "David Davis, the Secretary of State for Exiting the European Union, argued that the possibility to trigger Article 50 was based on the royal prerogative and so any consultation of elected members of parliament was unnecessary."

Comment: "In support of the contention that when passing the 2015 Act Parliament well knew of the Article 50 procedure for leaving the European Union if that was voted for in the referendum, he said that Parliament had previously dealt with it when the Lisbon Treaty was included in domestic law by the 2008 Act"

Comment: @user I don't see how that supports your argument at all that a European court would have nullified an internal member nations goverment action.

Comment: @Moo what are you talking about? I made no such argument, you are confusing me with someone else.

Answer (score 3):

What Moo has said is basically based on the UK dualism doctrine, in which the government cannot change laws without Parliament's' approval, even though the government *could* enter/break foreign treaties by itself.

Since the Constitutional Reform and Governance Act 2010 however, the Parliament is (in theory) even capable of blocking treaties that don't require any internal laws to enact them. Insofar they have not done this. More details are provided in this [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/41663/18373).

So Commons could have used the procedure spelled out in the 2010 Act to block article 50 invocation indefinitely and likewise for any Withdrawal Agreement, even (in the counterfactual scenario) in which these entailed no changes whatsoever to domestic UK laws.

Of course, what happens (and happened with Theresa May) in practice is that the Prime Minister effectively loses the majority's confidence after repeatedly butting against them, and resigns or is force out by a vote either in Commons or in their own party.

Answer (score 0):

The reason Brexit is a "whole sorry mess" is not because of *Miller*, it's because Brexit is a highly complicated, controversial, contentious issue and we still have no specific objective agreed among Leavers (what Brexit should look like), let alone among Leave and Remain, all these months/years later.

*Miller* 'merely' confirmed what should have already been known to all concerned: that Government may not change domestic law unless so authorised by statute (Parliament-made legislation). The referendum legislation and result did not give the Government such authorisation. The Government may have intended to proceed without authorisation but had no legal right to do so - if they had proceeded without Parliament's authorisation they would have committed a constitutional wrong. If *Miller* did prevent the Government from committing a constitutional wrong, *Miller* is hardly at fault for the consequences.

We can only speculate what would have happened without *Miller*, although I think we can be reasonably certain that Parliament would have involved itself if *Miller* hadn't happened. That said, *Miller* is useful support, useful ammunition - it's powerful to have judgments from the [High Court](http://www.bailii.org/ew/cases/EWHC/Admin/2016/2768.html) and then [Supreme Court](http://www.bailii.org/uk/cases/UKSC/2017/5.html) on your side, even though they don't say anything new about the constitution. Likewise, for some people it's a convenient fiction that *Miller* is to blame. They may even believe that.

But *Miller* did not give Parliament a new power. Nor did the judgments prescribe a process beyond saying 'our constitution says the Government must seek authorisation from Parliament to change domestic law' (I paraphrase). There's nothing in the High Court or Supreme Court judgments about "meaningful votes" and whatnot - that wasn't what the case was about. The judges didn't say Parliament must debate this in dozens of stages for nearly a year. They said, "For the reasons we have set out, we hold that the Secretary of State does not have power under the Crown's prerogative to give notice pursuant to Article 50 of the TEU for the United Kingdom to withdraw from the European Union.

[The European Union (Notification of Withdrawal) Act 2017](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2017/9/contents) is the result of that.

[The European Union (Withdrawal) Act 2018](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2017/9/contents), the legislation that has led to the meaningful votes etc, was originally drafted by Government and subsequently amended by Parliament during a series of debates and committee hearings because of *Government and Parliament's choices*. You can read the progress of the-then Withdrawal Bill at https://services.parliament.uk/bills/2017-19/europeanunionwithdrawal/stages.html.

It would have been constitutionally OK for Parliament to give the Government *carte blanche* with regard to Brexit immediately after *Miller* or any time since. It has not done so. Why not? Because whether Leave or Remain the majority of Parliamentarians want a say.

It may be helpful to compare/contrast this affair with the European Communities membership referendum of 1975. The Government and EC member states had previously negotiated and agreed in principle the new conditions of the UK's continued membership. The agreement with the EC was ready to be signed and its terms had been approved by Parliament. The referendum legislation bound the Government to act on the result - remain or leave. It was such that no further legislation was required to act on the result whatever it was. In the light of the past few years that looks like the model for how such things should be done.

Answer (score -1):

Moo has the right facts but comes to the wrong conclusion.

If it were not for Gina Miller then the government would not have had to pass legislation in order to trigger Article 50. It was the requirement for legislation that forced the government to offer a "meaningful vote" on the final deal. The Lords then further amended it to ensure that the motion for the meaningful vote was also amendable.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parliamentary_votes_on_Brexit

The specific reasoning that forced the need for a meaningful vote was that the prior Act autorizing the referendum was not adequate to authorize the triggering of Article 50 as well. It did not mention Article 50 and there was little to no debate about the leaving procedure before it was passed. The same logic also applied to the legislation passing the Withdrawal Agreement into law, although in that case the government did not argue the point having already lost twice (second time on appeal) in court.

The Lord ensured that the vote on the Withdrawal Agreement (the "deal") could itself be amended too. If no amendments had been possible then the government could have presented it as "take it or leave it", with the threat of crashing out with no deal hanging over MPs. By being able to amend the Act Parliament was able to reject it and propose an alternative way forward, which turned out to be asking the EU for an extension to Article 50.

Timeline:

**June 2016:** Questions are raised by academics and legal experts as to if the government needs an Act to leave the EU. The government responded that it thought it did not, and could [use prerogative powers instead](http://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=f43e102f-ea09-4449-b781-a35ecfe628fe).

**July 2016:** Gina Miller files her complaint.

**October 2016:** Hearing begins, government argues that the 2015 Act setting up the referendum knew of the Article 50 procedure and effectively authorized it.

**November 2016:** The court sides with Miller and holds that the government has no power to trigger Article 50 without a further Act. The reasoning given is that the prior legislation could not reasonably be considered to have authorized any and all future actions on the matter.

**January 2017:** As a result of the ruling the government introduces the European Union (Notification of Withdrawal) Act 2017. Due to the Miller ruling the government is forced to concede that both the triggering of Article 50 and the final deal should be put to Parliament.

Comment: The Government may not change Acts of Parliament unless authorised by Parliament. The Miller case confirmed that rule which the Government should have acted accordingly with in the first instance.

Comment: This is wrong, as various bits of UK law needed to be repealed and replaced in order to allow Brexit to legally happen - Gina Millers case or lack of it simply doesn't have the ability to allow the Government to enact or repeal laws by themselves, both of those things takes an act of Parliament.  See the [European Union (Withdrawal) Act 2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union_(Withdrawal)_Act_2018) as the most obvious example.

Comment: Right, but if it wasn't for the Miller case they would have done it anyway, hence the need for the case. That was the plan until she stepped in. That's what courts do, they enforce the law, but someone has to complain first, they don't actively investigate the government themselves.

Comment: @user you really aren't making any sense. Gina Millers case solely forced a vote in Parliament which was subsequently done 2 days after the ruling with one of the shortest passages ever, and passed with a huge majority.  The case accomplished nothing.

Comment: @Moo did you pay any attention to the actual vote? It was modified by the Lords and eventually created the legal requirement for a "meaningful vote" on the deal. The government very explicitly and clearly stated that it did not intend to have one otherwise.

Comment: @user Parliament could have asserted its power without the Miller case. Indeed Parliament could give the Government carte blanche with regard to Brexit, but it hasn't done so. Your position relies on a hypothetical scenario where Miller doesn't happen, the Government unilaterally changes domestic law (by some unknown mechanism) and Parliament does nothing.

Comment: @Lag I'm updating the answer to address this point.

Comment: @user The-then Brexit Secretary David Davis said after the High Court's judgment in November 2017 that "Parliament will have a central role in ensuring that we find the best way forward, and we have been clear that we will be as transparent and open as possible. There have already been a number of debates and parliamentary statements on Brexit, and the Prime Minister has pledged that that process will continue before article 50 is invoked." Even if that wasn't the Government's public position, I'm reasonably certain Parliament would have involved itself.

Comment: @Lag I'm sure Parliament would have involved itself. But the lack of a "meaningful vote" or any other way to effectively veto the Withdrawal Agreement would not have existed. The stark choice would have been May's deal or no deal, both of which were eventually rejected thanks to Miller.

Comment: @user "I'm sure Parliament would have involved itself." So as Miller granted no new power or motivation, how is Miller the cause of the delay and mess? Why hasn't Parliament given the Government carte blanche with regard to Brexit?

Comment: @Lag your Davis quote actually illustrates why Miller was so important. The Government fully intended to fudge it so that Parliament didn't have any meaningful say, just offer vague promises and claim that the debates were enough. Obviously at the time they knew that there was little chance of getting a deal that didn't rip the Tory Party apart, let along which would pass any kind of vote.

Comment: @user a big hole in your argument is that the Commons voted down the Lords amendments, so the European Union (Notification of Withdrawal) Act 2017 passed without the legal requirement for Parliament to have a "meaningful vote" on it - and if you doubt me, read the act itself as passed into legislation: http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2017/9/contents/enacted/data.htm Therefore, Gina Millers case changed *nothing*. She forced Parliament to have a vote, all parties rallied around and passed a "screw you" minimal compliance act, and the world moved on.

Comment: The actual amendment was put forward by Grieve in December, and was accepted due to pressure from the Miller case and the threat of further litigation, as well as pressure from MPs and the Lords. The Act itself only existed because Miller forced it to, the government having argued in court that it was unnecessary.

Comment: @user which amendment to which Act was put forward by Grieve? What further litigation was threatened on what grounds?

Comment: @Lag Clause 9 of the European Union (Withdrawal) Act 2018. Given the principal established by Miller in court, it was likely that if the government didn't offer any meaningful vote to Parliament there would have been further embarrassing legal action to force it to.

Comment: @user If the Government intended to commit the constitutional wrong of changing domestic law without authorisation from Parliament, I hope there would be an embarrassing legal action.